# How to put two tags in the same cell in table - HTML Bootstarp

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-4

I am new to html and bootstarp.
I want to create a table and when I create it, I saw the the inputs fields are not in all of the cell dimention., after change it to w=100, the % sign moved to another row
what I am missing?

```
<div class="card">
 <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-clean table-p-0 table-v-middle">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-lg-3">Inventory Type</th>
            <th class="col-lg-3">CTV (App)</th>
            <th class="col-lg-3">App (Mobile)</th>
            <th class="col-lg-3">Site (Desktop,Mobile))</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>Open Market</td>
           <td class="d-flex">
             <!-- CTV -->
             <span class="table-control-addon-right">%</span>
             <input type="number" class="w-100" step="0.1" max="100">
           </td>
           <!--  App -->
           <td class="d-flex">
             <span class="table-control-addon-right">%</span>
             <input type="number" class="w-100" step="0.1" max="100">
           </td>
           <!--  SITE -->
           <td class="d-flex">
             <span class="table-control-addon-right">%</span>
             <input type="number" class="w-100" step="0.1" max="100">
           </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>PMP</td>
           <td class="d-flex">
             <!-- CTV -->
             <span class="table-control-addon-right">%</span>
             <input type="number" class="w-100" step="0.1" max="100">
           </td>
           <!--  App -->
           <td class="d-flex">
             <span class="table-control-addon-right">%</span>
             <input type="number" class="w-100" step="0.1" max="100">
           </td>
           <!--  SITE -->
           <td class="d-flex">
             <span class="table-control-addon-right">%</span>
             <input type="number" class="w-100" step="0.1" max="100">
           </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

How I can make the input field and the % sign in the same row
[image]

[image]

This is what solved the issue

```
   <td>Open Market</td>
   <td class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">
     <!-- CTV -->
     <div class="d-flex" style="display: flex;">        <!-- need to add display flex -->
        <input type="number" class="w-100"  step="0.1"  max="100" style="border:none;">  <!-- need to add boarder none -->
        <span class="table-control-addon-right">%</span>
     </div>
   </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what solved the issue
add div tag before the input field
add style display flex in the div and add boarder none in the input

```
   <td>Open Market</td>
   <td class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">
     <!-- CTV -->
     <div class="d-flex" style="display: flex;">        <!-- need to add display flex -->
        <input type="number" class="w-100"  step="0.1"  max="100" style="border:none;">  <!-- need to add boarder none -->
        <span class="table-control-addon-right">%</span>
     </div>
       </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="number" class="w-100" step="0.1" max="100">
```

```html
<td class="d-flex">
             <!-- CTV -->
             <span class="table-control-addon-right">%</span>
             <input type="number table-control p-l-20" step="0.1" class="w-100" max="100">
           </td>
```

just add a class to your input tag "w-100"

Comment: when I perform the code the '%' move to another row and now it is not in the same line. I will add pic in the first post

Comment: check the second snippet you can add "d-flex" class to your <td> it will be in the same line after adding this.

Comment: sorry still no good, see my code i edited the question

Comment: I just want the % sign and the will be in the end of the input field. is it even possible?

Comment: "flex-row-reverse" add this as well just after the d-flex if you want the % sign after the input box or do you want % inside of the input box?

Comment: sorry still not work, I want it to be in the end of the input like an image and the user can not remove it